# Why is scale_fill_virdis overriding scale_fill_discrete?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run this code, the scale fill virdis command works but the scale fill discrete command right before it does not.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = mean_anxiety, fill = user_sex)) +

geom_density(alpha = .3) +

scale_x_continuous(name="Mean anxiety") +

scale_y_continuous(name= "density") +

scale_fill_discrete(name = "Gender", labels = c("Female", "Male", "Non-binary")) +
  
scale_fill_viridis_d(option = "E")
```

Comment: It's because you're trying to map 1 aesthetic (fill) to two scales. The last scale overrides the first scale. What is your intended outcome?

Comment: @teunbrand Well, I need to edit the key to have this title and labels, but it also needs to be in this colourblind colour. Is there a way to combine the lines or use different code which would stop it from overriding and achieve the same thing?